# Search (focus) as you type

Tags: ag-grid

When you start typing in Total commander grid with these settings

[image]

cursor is automatically being focused to respective line. I wonder if ag-grid allows something like this. And if yes, how should I please approach this issue?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Could you please add some more clarification? perhaps a picture of the grid, rather than the settings, of the expected behavior?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Lets say there is a column named Player and under this column header there are three values: Djokovic, Federer, Nadal. When Iam in the first cell (Djokovic) I start to type n and Nadal cell is focused then. In Nadal cell I start to type f and Federer cell is focused. And grid is scrolled to this position if needed...